# Write values to text boxes on web page with CefSharp

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I integrated CefSharp into my project. I was able to work out some points. However, I couldn't figure out how to check Inputboxes for example on a given site. So how can I write data into that InputBox. I request your help in this matter.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can modify/interact with the DOM using JavaScript see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#1-how-do-you-call-a-javascript-method-from-net

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to modify the content of your web page running inside CefSharp from the C# code directly. What you can do however is to pass javascript code that will run on the page and will change content.

For example, something similar to this:

```cs
var browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.example.com");
await browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('myTextBoxId').value='the value'");
```